# Kotlin Multiplatform and Gradle - How to move dependencies in separate file

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

In the multiplatform demo project all dependencies for the respective modules are in the KotlinSourceSet:

```kotlin
sourceSets {
    val jvmMain by getting {
        depenencies {
            implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:2.2.4")
        }
    }
}
```

Now the project grows quite large and I don't want hundreds of dependencies in the one build.gradle file. How do I move the imports into another file?
I couldn't find a solution to this aside from subprojects, composite builds and buildSrc.
Which all fail due to the multiplatform dependency function having the receiver type `KotlinDependencyHandler` and not `DependencyHandlerScope`.

Answer (score 0):

Have:

```
// Dependencies.kts
val kotlinDependencies: (Any) -> Unit = { target ->
    target.apply {
        implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:2.2.4")
        // Add more dependencies as needed
    }
}
```

then:

```
// build.gradle.kts
plugins {

}

configurations for multiplatform

kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            kotlinDependencies(this)
        }
    }
}
```

You define the dependencies in the Dependencies.kts script and then apply them to the respective source sets. The function kotlinDependencies can be reused for any source set you define within your Kotlin multiplatform project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created the `dependencies.gradle.kts` and filled it with your example. Then put the `apply(from = "dependencies.gradle.kts")` into the `dependencies` block of the sourceSet (where the implementation was in my example) and also some other places to test, but no matter where I put it the error `dependencies.gradle.kts:19:5: Unresolved reference: implementation` comes up. Edit: IntelliJ Idea also says that it cannot load code insight for `dependencies.gradle.kts`

Comment: ok i updated answer with another idea.

Comment: Thanks. I am not very proficient with gradle, he says he cannot resolve `kotlinDependencies`. I think I have to reference `Dependencies.kts` somewhere in my `build.gradle.kts`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use precompiled script plugins. I found this way in JetBrains samples
https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/tree/master/examples/todoapp/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin

Create *.gradle.kts in buildScr/scr/main/kotlin with the scope of dependencies like this

[image]

Then use it as plugin

[image]